# Does JavaEE have Inversion of Control?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, cdi

My question is more conceptual, rather than practical.
I have read about **IoC** and **DI**, and I think that I have understood those concepts (IoC is more general than DI, there are other ways to realize IoC).
In all articles when one says **IoC**, it is mentioned frameworks like **Spring**, etc.

However, I did not see any where if **JavaEE** does make Inversion of Control, or not.
So, I want to know this, to digest these concepts better.

I am not searching any pro's, con's, etc.

Simply:

JavaEE does also have **DI**, through **CDI**.

- Is **JavaEE** considered as having **IoC**, or not?
- Why?
- If not, what does it lack to be considered like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependency injection in IoC is not a feature of a language, rather it's a feature of a framework/platform/library. As such, DI present in JEE is a good example of inversion of control so yes, JEE "has" it.

You should understand, though, that DI is not the only technique of inversion of control. Another would be, for instance [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

**Edit:** [This article](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html) seems to be a good overview of IoC in general and various flavours of it.

Comment: But the language is Java, JavaEE is collection of specifications, libraries, etc. No? Why would be wrong to ask if JEE has it?

Comment: That's what I said: "DI present in JEE is a good example of inversion of control" ;) As side note, [this article](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html) seems to be a good overview of IoC. It also states that "EJBs are a good example of this style of inversion of control. When you develop a session bean, you can implement various methods that are called by the EJB container at various lifecyle points.".

Comment: Ok, as you has started "DI is not a feature of a language", I thought if to ask this is even wrong.

Answer (score 0):

CDI is the technical name of JEE's IOC and is specified by JSR 299 : 
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhb.html